# Looking for simpler solution to group by and select rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
id c1 c2 c3
101  a b c
102  b c d
103  d e f
101  h i j
102  k l m
```

I want to select rows based on grouping on **`id`** column where `count > 1`

The result should be all rows whose `id` had more than 1 entry

Expected result:

df:

```
id c1 c2 c3
101  a b c
102  b c d
101  h i j
102  k l m
```

I am able to achieve this with below code I wrote.

```
g = df.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name='counts')
filt = g.query('counts > 1')
m_filt = df.id.isin (filt.id)
df_filtered= df[m_filt]
```

Wanted to check if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.groupby('id').transform('size')['id'].gt(1)]
```

Or if need all duplicated rows use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
df[df.duplicated('id', keep=False)]
```

Or similar:

```
df[df['id'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Comment: I got "TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types" when I tried this.

Comment: @GZ0 - oops, I forget define one column

Comment: Well, the correct way should be `df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('size')`. It would be better that you run the code before posting it.

Comment: @GZ0 - Sure, I know it, but I forget for it... But you are 100% right.

Comment: @GZ0 Thanks. I fit your code in the 1st solution suggested by jazrael and it worked.. Can you guys please share any useful links or material where i could learn how to properly use groupby? There are many parameters and I am often getting confused on how to use the columns in this topic.

Comment: @HarikrishnanBalachandran Start with the [manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
result = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1)
```